# sklearn support vector machine is not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, image-recognition

I am trying to classify images using `sklearn`'s `svm.SVC` classifier, but it's not learning, after training I got 0.1 accuracy (there are 10 classes, so 0.1 accuracy is the same as a random guess)

I am using the [CIFAR-10](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~kriz/cifar.html) datatset. 10000 images that are represented as 3072 `uint8`s. The first 1024 are the red pixels, the second 1024 are the green pixels and the thirst 1024 are the blue pixels.

Each image also has a label, which is a number 0-9

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib

train_data = pickle.load(open('data_batch_1','rb'), encoding='latin1')
test_data = pickle.load(open('test_batch','rb'), encoding='latin1')

X_train = np.array(train_data['data'])
y_train = np.array(train_data['labels'])
X_test = np.array(test_data['data'])
y_test = np.array(test_data['labels'])

clf = svm.SVC(verbose=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

joblib.dump(clf, 'Cifar-10-clf.pickle')

print(accuracy)
```

Does anyone know what my problem could be or can point me to resources to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure but I think that you need to tune the parameters of SVC.

I tested some parameters for learning then I got an `0.318` accuracy.

here is code:

```
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
import cPickle

train_data = cPickle.load(open('data/data_batch_1', 'rb'))
test_data = cPickle.load(open('data/test_batch', 'rb'))

X_train = np.array(train_data['data'])
y_train = np.array(train_data['labels'])
X_test = np.array(test_data['data'][:1000])
y_test = np.array(test_data['labels'][:1000])

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=10, gamma=0.01)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

print "Accuracy: ", accuracy
```

And I recommend `grid search function` for auto tuning the hyper-parameters.

[This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) is public documents about `tuning the hyper-parameters` in scikit-learn